# socket.io Error GET https://example.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LWAaR9P

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am new to node.js and socket.io please help me solve the below problem

I have chat server, it was working fine, suddenly it stopped working and when I see in the console it shows the following lines in red

This is mozilla firefox

> GET
>   https://spacecasino.co.uk:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LWAaR9P
>   567 seconds

and in chrome

> GET https://spacecasino.co.uk:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LWAa-RP net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are using a self signed certificate which is not trusted by the browser. That's why both browsers complain. You might have clicked through the warning in firefox so that firefox does trust it now for you but for me firefox does not trust it either.

Comment: Thank you bro, for your time and comment . But before chat  was working fine..... Suddenly it stopped working... I really don't wat to do  please help me bro