# Socket.io How to use ssl certificate in socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl

I was getting the following error net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE in chrome so I posted a question [socket.io Error GET https://example.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LWAaR9P](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40301901/socket-io-error-get-https-example-com3000-socket-io-eio-3transport-polling/40304330#40304330). The answer was that I might be using self signed certificate. So how to use certificate provided by certificate authority. There are certificates in cpanel -> ssl/tls->certificates

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
var ioSocket = io('https://', {
    'reconnection delay': 2500,
    'secure':true,  // this will make socket.io to respond over https
    'max reconnection attempts': 10,
    'reconnection':true
});
```